# Fibonacci numbers integer taken

Tags: python, integer, fibonacci

I have 2 questions about Fibonacci numbers.

1) The number of integers taken as an argument into the Fibonacci base functions? (in Turkish: Argüman olarak alınan onluk tabanda ki sayıyı Fibonacci tabanına dönüştüren işlev?)

2) The number given in the Fibonacci function converts integer base? (in Turkish: Fibonacci tabanında verilmiş sayıyı onluk tabana dönüştüren işlev?)

```
a, b = 0, 1
print (a)
print (b)
i = 2
while i<=50:
    a,b = b, a+b
    print (b)
    i+=1
```

i can wrote that, but i want such as something like f(10) or f(5)

I'm sorry, my english isn't so good. Thank you.

Comment: What's your issue, more specifically, what's going wrong?

Comment: At a guess he wants a direct formula for calculating fibonacci numbers, rather than via a loop.

Comment: @Iplodman it's print up to 50 fibonacci numbers. i want to only one, for example f(6).

Comment: @Phylogenesis yes, something like that. i want only one fibonacci number

Comment: You need to use [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Philippe_Marie_Binet) to calculate individual members of the sequence.

Comment: @Phylogenesis how can i write Binet's formula on python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move it all to a function and handle special cases.

```
def fib(n):
    #TODO: handle invalid case(negative or non-int) and return

    if(n == 0):
        print(0)
        return

    if(n == 1):
        print(1)
        return

    a, b = 0, 1
    i = 2
    #this will go up to the n-th number
    while i<=n:
        a,b = b, a+b
        i+=1

    print (b)
```

Then you can do this:

```
fib(1)
fib(0)
fib(6)
fib(33)
```

And you'll get:

```
1
0
8
3524578
```

Comment: A much simpler solution is possible, if you remove `print` from the function, throw away `i` and `return a`. (my version has 6 lines)

Comment: I wrote it so it matches OP's needs. OP printed and kept track of `i`, so I decided to do the same.

Comment: I think the code is harder to understand with these special cases.